# MySQL Trigger On UPDATE "Unknown Column" Error

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.5, trigger, update

I want to log a table when it is updating a row in which the value of the "insertDate" or "updateDate" column is older than 3 months.

I wrote this trigger:

```
DELIMITER ///
CREATE TRIGGER `trig_before_up_dad_records` BEFORE UPDATE ON `dad_records` FOR EACH ROW
                                                                               BEGIN

SET @beforeThreeMonth = DATE(NOW() - interval 3 month);

IF (ISNULL(OLD.updateDate) OR UNIX_TIMESTAMP(OLD.updateDate) IS NULL) THEN
    SET @lastDate = DATE(OLD.insertDate);
ELSE
    SET @lastDate = DATE(OLD.updateDate);
END IF;

IF(UNIX_TIMESTAMP(lastDate) < UNIX_TIMESTAMP(beforeThreeMonth)) THEN
    INSERT INTO three_month_ago_dad_records SELECT OLD.*;
END IF;
END;
///
```

When update a row where the `updateDate` time 2015-04-09 (or anything older than 3 months) I get the following error:

> /* SQL Error (1054): Unknown column 'lastDate' in 'field list' */

However, I didn't write `lastDate` as a column. Where is my error?

Comment: What is this then?: `IF(UNIX_TIMESTAMP(lastDate) ...`

Comment: hmm yes i'm edited the trigger. but now return to me _/* SQL Error (1051): Unknown table 'OLD' */_ so i'm updated trigger like this: `INSERT INTO three_month_ago_dad_records SELECT * FROM OLD;` this time return to me _/* SQL Error (1146): Table 'adserver.OLD' doesn't exist */_ Last option i'm wrote a query: `INSERT INTO three_month_ago_dad_records SELECT * FROM dad_records WHERE id = OLD.id;` and successfully executed ;) thank you @ypercube

Comment: Yes, `OLD` and `NEW` are not tables in MySQL, so you can't have `OLD.*` or `NEW.*`.

Answer (score 1):

Get rid of `UNIX_TIMESTAMP()` everywhere.  `DATETIME` fields can be compared directly.

Once you have done that, you will probably notice the missing `@` that is causing the error.

I think it can be simplified down to only:

```
CREATE TRIGGER ...
IF COALESCE(OLD.updateDate, OLD.insertDate) < CURRENT_DATE() - interval 3 month
    INSERT INTO three_month_ago_dad_records SELECT OLD.*;
END IF;
END;
```